# Suggest me some good seller for Arduino UNO

Tags: arduino-uno, robotics, project

I want to start a new project with arduino uno and want to make some amazing mini projects, but i am confused that from where should i buy. So please suggest me some affordable robotic stores.

Comment: I'm sorry, this is an opinion-based question. Your question is very likely to be deleted. But as stated below, you can always check aliexpress.com.

Answer (score 2):

I recently bought some arduino nano V3 on Aliexpress. It cost me €1.75,- so I immediately bought 4 :P arrived within 10 days. Also the arduino uno R3 (non-official) is only €3,-. Worth the try? I would say definitely, because if you need it for a project you want to leave it in not take it out because you have another idea. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanx weaverworm for this suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

***I would comment, but my rep is not high enough so consider this a comment:***

Welcome to StackExchange. You should maybe take a look at some guidelines on how to ask good questions.

**First of all:** mind your tune! ASAP in capitals is very impolite and implies a request we MUST fulfil - no we don't. Try to use please and thank you and everyone will be happy.

**Second:** this is a Q&A Site to help people now and in the future, so most of the time questions like: where can I buy this or what book is good are not what this is made for because they won't be valid for very long and have been asked many times before (but answers lost their validity as mentioned above).

**and last but not least:** Google it. Ebay, Aliexpress, Amazon... whatever you fancy. There are many Arduino clones for low prices around. I bought a few UNOs for like 6€ each. They work fine.

With that in mind: welcome again. I hope you find many useful answers around.

Comment: ok i understand, this is a first and last mistake.